# How to increase pressure sensor breadboard sensitivity?

Tags: sensor, breadboard, pressure, sensitivity

I build a pressure sensor breadboard according to the schematic. It works, but has quite low sensitivity - it shows some pressure only after big pressure is applied.

Is there a way to increase sensitivity by replacing some components with different values, without redesigning the  PCB?

[image]

Comment: *" it shows some pressure"* What is the result, how are you measuring it? Please specify some quantitative data like volts or milli-volts.

Comment: There is 0.08V on output when no pressure is applied, so my arduino analog pin reads 0. When I apply much pressure, it reads 1 and there are over 0.1 v. I would like to see readings starting from little pressure apply

Comment: You'll need to provide the datasheet for the sensor - to check its output impedance relative to the circuit, and its common mode output voltage.

Comment: The sensor is MPS20N0040D. 
Input impedance of 4 - 6 KΩ,
The output impedance of 4 - 6 KΩ,
Full-scale output voltage 50 - 100 mV,
Bridge Resistance to 4 - 6 KΩ,

Answer (score 1):

Without bothering about any of the other questions, if the zero-pressure output of your sensor is zero, just increase R8 by whatever factor you want.  If the zero-pressure output is not zero, if you make R8 too big you will saturate.